# How do I update the XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT variable in magento?

Tags: magento

I see:

```
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT  = 'contacts/email/recipient_email';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER     = 'contacts/email/sender_email_identity';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE   = 'contacts/email/email_template';
    const XML_PATH_ENABLED          = 'contacts/contacts/enabled';
```

When I echo XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, I see "hello@example.com" but don't see it in a file search of my project and am not sure where to configure it in the admin or database.

Any advice on where to look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the Magento is first installed, each Module's got its own default values defined for the System Configuration section. So for your case, if you go to the Magento Admin's System Configuration section, then you need to follow these steps to find where you can set the required value:-

- Click the "Contacts" tab in the left panel.
- In the "Email Options" section, you will find the label "Send Emails To", whose value you need to change & Magento provides the default value for this field as "`hello@example.com`".

Whenever you change any of the default values in the Magento Admin's System Configuration section, that data will get saved into the database. Otherwise the default data (if any) is fetched from each corresponding module's "`config.xml`" file, in the node:-

```
<config>
  <default>
    .....
  </default>
</config>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this hello@example.com in magento2.x from admin section as follows

Storre->Configuration->General->Contacts->Email options.

[image]